# How can data from two elements JW Player for Google Analytics are passed?

Tags: video, google-analytics, jwplayer

JW Player transmits data to Google Analytics incorrect.
Two JW Player videos on one page.
Have the following case:

```
<html>
…
<div id=”myvideo1” class="video" data-video-height="140" data-video-width="350" data-video-titel="my test titel 1” data-video-file=”path_to_the_file” data-video-image=”path_to_the_image”></div>
…
<div id=”myvideo2” class="video" data-video-height="290" data-video-width="500" data-video-titel="my test titel 2” data-video-file=”path_to_the_file” data-video-image=”path_to_the_image”></div>
…
<!-- in footer of the page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load( function(e)  
{
    var id, height = 0, width = 0, tite, file, image, sources;
    $('.video').each( function(  )
    {
            id     = $(this).attr('id');     
            titel  = $(this).attr('data-video-titel');
            height = $(this).attr('data-video-height');
            width  = $(this).attr('data-video-width');
            image  = $(this).attr('data-video-image');
            file   = $(this).attr('data-video-file');

            sources = [ {'file': file } ];

       jwplayer( id ).setup({
            'height': height,
            'width': width,
            'image': image,
            'sources': sources,
            'events': {
                  onPlay: function (event) {
                        console.log("onPlay::titel: "+titel+", "+jwplayer( id ).getPosition().toFixed(0));                         
                        ga('send', 'event', 'Video Play', titel, event.newstate+": "+jwplayer( id ).getPosition() );
                  },
                  onPause: function (event) {
                         console.log("onPause::titel: "+titel+", "+jwplayer( id ).getPosition().toFixed(0));                         
                         ga('send', 'event', 'Video Pause', titel, event.newstate+": "+jwplayer( id ).getPosition().toFixed(0) +" ( "+id+")" );
                  }
             }
        });
    });
   });
```

Here I've shown only two cases for Google Analytic, play and pause.
When you click the second video, with the ID "myvideo2", the data is transferred correctly, I click on the first video "myvideo1" will taken out of the second video data!
What must be accurate this source code?
To transfer the data correctly to google?

regards

Comment: Hi Ethan, 
I send you email with the link to the page.

Comment: Problem solved, got a tip that needs to declare the variables found in each loop instead

Comment: Ah, glad you got it!